# Android calls methods out of turn

Tags: android, methods

This has really got me stuck, when clicking a `Button` in my Android application it seems that the methods are being called out of sync. When I click the `Button` below I want to call:

```
loc = new Location(Options.this);
```

Once that has finished I then want to call:

```
setLocationPref();
```

What happens in reality is that when my program enters the method below "displayLocations" it jumps back to the button again and calls:

```
setLocationPref();
```

**I believe the error lies in the two lines of code:**

```
builder.setItems(cs, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item){
```

If anyone has any ideas please let me know, many thanks :)

```
/** Location selection */
bLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLocation);
bLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

        loc = new Location(Options.this);

        loc.locationSelection();

        setLocationPref();
    }
});
```

The code jumps back where I have written /** FAILS HERE */

```
/** Display locations in a list */
public void displayLocations(){

Log.d("displayLocations", "displayLocations ");

LocationSQL getSetLocation = new LocationSQL(context);

final ArrayList<String> locations = locSQL.allLocations();
final CharSequence[] cs = locations.toArray(new CharSequence[locations.size()]);
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
builder.setTitle("Pick your location.");
builder.setItems(cs, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item){

        /** FAILS HERE */

        Toast.makeText(context, cs[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        String selectedLocation = locations.get(item);
        updateLocationInfo(selectedLocation); 
    }
});
builder.create().show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to remember that in Android dialogs are not handled in a serial fashion.  E.g. when I code my SWT application on a PC, I can wait till the dialog has been responded to, and then I go back to doing whatever next there was to do. Not so in Android. You display a dialog and life goes on - immediately.  Thus, what probably happens is this:

Your call to loc.locationSelection() calls displayLocations(). While displayLocations() starts doing its work, the control in the button listener gets round to its next task, which is setLocationPref();

Another important thing is that in Android you should not really try to display your own dialogs like you are doing, because this will not handle such things as state changes on screen rotation or when user switches between your app and other apps and your application is suspended (killed) for a time.  You need to create your alert in onCreateDialog() and then prepare it in onPrepareDialog() and display the dialog with showDialog() - at least this is how it used to be up until recently until DialogFragment came around (see below).  The OS will then take care of the rest - you need to trust it.

Do not call .show() on the dialog directly!  The system will do it for you.

Note that this way of doing things has been superseded by DialogFragment.  However, I think it is good and educational for anybody to do it the old way at least once.  Here is a comment I wrote for myself when trying to understand state changes and how to handle dialogs the conventional way, before DialogFragment.  I hope it helps.

```
//=============================================================================
// Note re. handling of application kill, screen rotation and other state
// change events:
//
// Android will re-execute the onCreate() method for such events.
// Actually, the whole object gets re-created even for a screen rotation!
// If you put a static counter in the constructor, you will see that the
// constructor gets re-executed and all the non-static variables get scrapped
// and re-created.  The saving grace is that the rotation or other such events
// do not immediately interrupt when you are in the middle of executing a
// method, but rather it gets queued to be handled when its turn comes (or so
// I hope, else there would have chaos).
// Thus data consistency is not threatened and we can plan to recover from
// such situations gracefully.
//
// The only data that is safe is static class data, or you can - or rather
// should
// - save data as Android advises, by means of
//      onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() and
//      getLastNonConfigurationInstance()
// (deprecated in API 13 and replaced by
//      setRetainInstance(boolean)).
// Note that to save data across complete application restart from a cold
// kill you would need to use:
//      onSaveInstanceState() and
//      onRestoreInstanceState().
// See
// http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html ).
//
// Using statics is probably OK if you are feeling a bit lazy.
// It will probably take care of the state changes, but not of the complete
// kill, of course.
//
// If doing it the proper way, however, we use a clear and simple contract
// with the OS:
//
// 1. We need to save/restore our data before/after a state change or being
//    suspended.  We do this using onRetainNonConfigurationInstance(),
//    getLastNonConfigurationInstance() for state changes - or equivalent
//    dialog fragment functionality - and using onSaveInstanceState() and
//    onRestoreInstanceState() for application being suspended.
//
// 2. We also need to ensure that all onCreateDialog() and
//    onPrepareDialog() methods (or their equivalents, if using the dialog
//    fragment API) can be meaningfully executed on the application being
//    re-constituted after a state change or after being suspended and
//    re-activated.  The OS will execute onCreateDialog() always on
//    application re-activation, and will execute onPrepareDialog() if the
//    dialog was opened at the time the state change or application suspension
//    took place (or if it was opened at any time in the past - see below!)
//
// 3. Therefore all data that is required for re-constituting dialogs
//    (for onCreateDialog() and onPrepareDialog() if this model is used in
//    preference to dialog fragment), must be available all the time and must
//    be saved in onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() and in
//    onSaveInstanceState().
//
// 4. It also means that we cannot re-use or clean any variables whose
//    function Is to 'deliver' information to e.g. onPrepareDialog().  If
//    these variables are re-initialized or otherwise overwritten after the
//    dialog has been displayed, they will not be available when the OS
//    attempts to re-run these methods to re-constitute the dialog!
//
// WARNING:
// Remember not to try to prevent the re-creation of these dialogs or
// otherwise hand onto those dialog instances (e.g. by means of static
// variables), because they are likely to reference your screen GUI and if
// you use the old (eg. pre-rotation) instances, they will try to reference
// non-existing variables from the old instance of the application, and things
// might get funny and actually crash.
//
// IMPORTANT:
// Also note that during such re-creations of the screen, user input fields
// (fields that are user-writable) on the screen will NOT be overwritten, even
//  if we try to overwrite them.  This is good, because it means that if we
// preserve our read-only data over the rotation, the system will preserve
// whatever the user might have typed in.
//
// NOTE:
// Additional note re. onPrepareDialog()
// (This actually might be a bug in Android)
//
// It seems the Android will call onPrepareDialog() on screen rotation, even if
// the dialog is not currently displayed.  Perhaps it will also be called at
// other times.  It does not seem to be called on normal app startup or on app
// re-creation after it is suspended, but best to be safe and assume that the
// method will be generally called immediately after onCreateDialog() even if
// the dialog is not active (displayed).
//
// Therefore:
// - All data that the onPrepareDialog() needs must always be provided or
//   suitable dummy substitutes must be given or the method should quietly exit
//   early if such data is not found.
// - The dialog must not try to do any actions that affect the main
//   application data, unless the data we have for it is real and we are sure
//   that the  dialog is really going to be displayed: Such actions are perhaps
//   not common but one could conceivably put such actions in onPrepareDialog()
//   (in places other than listeners, where such actions are common place), but
//   if we use dummy data or exit early, such actions will obviously be
//   nonsensical.
//
//  However, the whole scheme of using onCreateDialog/onPrepareDialog has been
//  deprecated and therefore will not be fixed even if this thing here
//  is an error.
//=============================================================================
```